# NullPointerException in Android when declaring a Content Provider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm facing a strange issue when declaring a Content Provider in my project. I'm copying the classes and Manifest declaration from another project of my own. It's working OK on my other project.

Here's part of my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.qr"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="540"
    android:versionName="5.4" >

(...)

<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launch" >

(...)

<provider
            android:name=".provider.HistoryProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.qr.History"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:readPermission="com.example.qr.History.read"
            android:writePermission="com.example.qr.History.write" />

(...)

    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I run my app, I get this stack trace:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4783)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4430)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is **the whole stack trace**. No '*com.example*' trace is included. Of course some code in my app is producing this but the actual crash happens in Android.

Because my own classes are not included in the stack trace, I really don't know where to look.

I've run the code in an emulator with Android 4.2 and I've compared it with the source code of that version of Android, so I know the crash is produced in this line of ActivityThread:

```
4782            ApplicationInfo ai = info.applicationInfo;
4783            if (context.getPackageName().equals(ai.packageName)) {
```

[Here's a link to the source code of this class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#ActivityThread.installProvider%28android.content.Context,android.app.IActivityManager.ContentProviderHolder,android.content.pm.ProviderInfo,boolean,boolean,boolean%29).

If I don't declare the content provider (i.e. if I remove  from my Manifest), the app works perfectly.

I've added some logs to my Application class, as well as the main Activity class. The crash is produced before either is launched.

**So, my question is**: what in my code can be producing *context*, *context.getPackageName()* or *info.applicationInfo* to be *null* during installation?

**EDIT**

When triggering the stack trace in the emulator several times, I only get this between traces:

```
09-11 23:10:21.250: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 23:10:21.470: D/dalvikvm(933): GC_CONCURRENT freed 142K, 9% free 2951K/3224K, paused 78ms+3ms, total 225ms
09-11 23:10:44.030: I/Process(933): Sending signal. PID: 933 SIG: 9
09-11 23:10:46.940: D/dalvikvm(947): GC_CONCURRENT freed 164K, 10% free 2711K/2996K, paused 13ms+114ms, total 201ms
09-11 23:10:47.170: I/ActivityThread(947): Pub com.example.qr.History: com.example.qr.provider.HistoryProvider
09-11 23:10:47.170: D/AndroidRuntime(947): Shutting down VM
09-11 23:10:47.170: W/dalvikvm(947): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
09-11 23:10:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: what is the package name in your provider class?

Comment: Provider's package is com.example.qr.provider

Comment: You might want to clean your project and try using the fully qualified name of your provider in the manifest..

Comment: In eclipse scroll up in LogCat and look for hints above this FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Thanks @Varun, I cleaned everything and tried android:name="la.droid.qr.provider.HistoryProvider" with exactly the same result.

Comment: same result? works or still having issues

Comment: @Varun Still having issues. I get a NullPointerException on line 4783 of ActivityThread

Comment: Thanks @Erik, I can't find anything helpful. Please read my Edit.

Comment: @Erik What part of my code do you think it'd be worth showing? Because the crash happens before the app is really started, I don't think the problem is in the Provider implementation.